# How to disable notifications to install google chrome when using microsoft EDGE?

Tags: google-chrome, microsoft-edge

I've tried installing several extensions to disable notifications, but all to no avail.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNZDG.png

Answer (score -1):

1. Set Google as default search engine on Edge.
2. Search directly from the Edge tab instead of opening google.com

Enjoy!